# how to add a blank line contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, forms, recaptcha, contact-form

I'm new to [wordpress](/questions/tagged/wordpress) and I am using `Contact Form 7` for a form on the website. At the bottom of the form, I've added recaptcha and then the send button. I want to add a SPACE between the end of recaptcha and the form.

What code should I add there? 
The code looks like this.

```
[recaptcha]

[submit "Send"]
```

And the screenshot looks like this.

[image: screenshot of recaptcha too close to send button]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As [Fralec_](http://www.stackoverflow.com/users/4575054/fralec) pointed out, you can use a line break `<br />` between the shortcodes to nudge the "Send" button down:

```
[recaptcha]
<br />
[submit "Send"]
```

Alternatively, if you want more control over the spacing, I would suggest wrapping the "Send" button inside a `<div>` with inline styling applied to it (change the `20px` value accordingly), like this:

```
[recaptcha]
<div style="margin-top: 20px;">
  [submit "Send"]
</div>
```

**Resources**

- [CSS Margins](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp)

Comment: Sorry, it works. You must to REPUBLISH the PAGE that holds CR7 code to apply the change!

Comment: <br /> did not work for me, but <br> or <br/> worked.

Comment: div margin worked for me, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
[recaptcha]<br/>

[submit "Send"]
```

Comment: Thank you @Fralec .

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me, until I added an HTML space then a line break, like this:

```
[recaptcha]
&nbsp<br>
[submit "Send"]
```

However, using `div` inline styling is the proper way, as you should not rely on `<br>` for cosmetics and layout.  Using `<br>` is not for responsive web sites or accessibility like screen readers.

[Source](https://blog.hubspot.com/website/html-accessibility?hubs_content=blog.hubspot.com%2Fwebsite%2Fhtml-line-break&hubs_content-cta=makes%20your%20code%20less%20accessible)